# jquery to get non-unique IDs from the DOM

Tags: jquery, dom

say i have these two uniquely ID'd divs with input elements that are not uniquely ID'd inputs.

```
<div id="column1" >
    ...
    <input checked="checked" type="checkbox" name="days" value="1" id="id_days_0" />
</div>

<div id="column2" >
    ...
    <input checked="checked" type="checkbox" name="days" value="1" id="id_days_0" />
</div>
```

how can i differentiate between the two inputs based on the top level div ID?

Obviously, this does not work:

```
$('#id_days_0').attr('checked')
```

Is there a way to only focus on one input's ID from within a particular div?

Comment: $('#column1 #id_days_0').attr('checked')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As previously mentioned, you should always make your IDs unique and subsituting a class would be a good approach.

With that being said, you may reference the necessary items as follows:

HTML:

```
<div id="column1" >
    First <input checked="checked" type="checkbox" name="days" value="Chk1" id="id_days_0" />
</div>
<div id="column2" >
    Second <input checked="checked" type="checkbox" name="days" value="Chk2" id="id_days_0" />
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
alert("Check1 = "+$("#column1 #id_days_0").val()+"\n"+"Check2 = "+$("#column2 #id_days_0").val());
```

The reason that this *can* work, is due to the referencing of the objects based off of referencing the parent first, and then the child.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/8VqtE/

Comment: @nnachefski, did you read about the IDs that needed to be unique? In your comment you are still using the non-unique IDs...

Answer (score 0):

Adding a parent to your selector should do the trick:

```
$('#column1 #id_days_0')
$('#column2 #id_days_0')
```

Comment: While this will probably work, you shouldn't have IDs with the same name on the same page.

Comment: Agreed, however a poorly designed third party library that the OP is stuck with for some silly reason may be causing this issue.  I'm assuming that the HTML is being generated externally and OP is stuck with it.

Answer (score 0):

This is bad practice, no two elements on the same page should have the same ID. A better method would be to have

```
<div id="column1">
    <input ... class="days_0" />

</div>
<div id="column2">
    <input ... class="days_0" />
</div>
```

Then you can find #column1, and filter down to .days_0

Answer (score 0):

You should never duplicate ID's!

However, this works in Chrome:

`$('#column2').find('#id_days_0')`

Answer (score 0):

As already is stated: IDs **must** be unique, so you need to change your design.

For example you can use classes, these do not require to be unique:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="days" value="1" class="class_days" />
```

Now you can use jQuery to find the correct input using:

```
$('#column_0 .class_days')
```