# ajax() function, within an each(), push response to array, async

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous, each

I have a ajax request within an each() loop.

My first issue was that code outside of the each loop was executing prior to the each() loop completing (async).

I resolved this with the approach mentioned here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17904856/1560199

The each loop now pushes each ajax response **Object** to the array, and once complete proceeds as required.

The problem I have is that I can't seem to use responseJSON directly on the ajax Object:

```
$comment_response_array = [];
$.each($message_id_array, function(message_key, message_id){
   $comment_response_array.push($.fn.get_comments(message_id, $last_refresh).responseJSON);
});
```

The $.fn.get_comments eventually maps through the this ajax request:

```
$.fn.ajax_request = function($method, $ajax_file, $data) {
    return $.ajax({
        'type': $method,
        'url': '../../ajax/' + $ajax_file + '.php',
        'data': $data,
        'dataType': "json"
    });
};
```

With this, `$comment_response_array` returns an array of undefined Objects.

Just looking for some guidance on whether I am taking the correct approach and just missing something simple, or if I need to change my approach any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: The `return $.ajax` returns a promise, not a response - have a look at this link under **deferred objects**: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323

Comment: @freedomn-m Thanks for this.  I have changed over to this, but outside the each loop `$comment_response_array = [];` is still empty.  I have tried the when() done() approach with the each loop with no success.  The problem is I do not want my `$comment_response_array` to be actioned inside the each loop itself, but once the each loop has finished.