# How to get one time alert inside JQuery post method within loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 4 items data to post and get the response data 4 time because i post the data inside the loop.
after that i also get alert 4 time but i want to show one time alert after 4 data post.

```js
<script>

 $('#save').on('click',function(){   
  var i =1;
  //i have 4 item 
  $('.item').each(function() {  
   
   $.post( "example.php", { id: i })
   .done(function( data ) {
       
    alert(0); // just one time
    
       
   });

   i++; 
  });
   

        })
</script>
```

Comment: You can try jQuery.when().

Comment: Hope this helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17904704/jquery-ajax-solution-inside-each-loop. Use `when` as @XiaodanMao suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Try similar code

```
<script>

$('#save').on('click',function(){   
    var i =1;
            var cnt=0;
    //i have 4 item 
    $('.item').each(function() {        

        $.post( "example.php", { id: i })
        .done(function( data ) {
            cnt++;
                    if (cnt==4) {
                        alert(0); //for one time after all items post.  
                    }

        });

        i++;    
    });


       })
</script>
```

Hope this will help you!.

Comment: if post data are fail it also alert. i just need to alert one time after the response inside done function. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can try by setting the counter like given below.

```
$('#save').on('click',function(){   
    var i =1;
    var counter = $('.item').length -1;
    //i have 4 item 
    $('.item').each(function() {        
        $.post( "example.php", { id: i })
        .done(function( data ) {
              if(counter == 0)
                   alert(0); //for one time after all items post.            
           counter = counter ==0 ? 0: counter -1;
        });
        i++;    
    });
});
```

Comment: I think @Amol had updated the answer before me and his answer is almost same as mine so if it is correct Accept his ans first :)

Answer (score 0):

By using `jQuery.when()` and `deferred.resolve` at `jQuery.ajax` `complete` event

you could gather all requests and see which one succeed and which one failed.

Try running the code below, but please note there are no `example.php` on stackoverflow, so you'll see all 4 requests failed.

```js
jQuery(function($) {

  // make all requests
  var requests = $('.item').map(function(idx, elm) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();

    $.ajax({
      method: 'post',
      url: 'example.php',
      data: { id: idx + 1 },
      complete: deferred.resolve
    });

    return deferred;
  });

  // when all requests are done.
  $.when.apply($, requests).done(function() {

    var stats = { success: 0, error: 0 };

    // count how many of them succeed or failed.
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
      stats[arguments[i][1]]++;
    }

    // print resullt.
    console.log(
      arguments.length + ' Requests completed, ' +
      stats.success + ' Succeeded, ' +
      stats.error + ' Failed.'
    );

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="save">Save</button>

<div class="item">Item 1</div>
<div class="item">Item 2</div>
<div class="item">Item 3</div>
<div class="item">Item 4</div>
```